# Fffmpeg drawtext filter creating large output file size and taking high cpu?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, filtering

I have a video input file on which i am drawing a user porvided text on it. I am able to draw text on video file using drawtext filter of ffmpeg and it works file, but main issue arises with ffmpeg command.

That is when i run my ffmpeg command then three things happens:-
1. The output video file size is larger then input file size.
2. The output video file loses quality of video than input video file.
3. The cpu is going very high.

The ffmpeg command that is am using is-

```
ffmpeg -i input1.asf -vf drawtext="fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf: \text='Stack Overflow': fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5: \boxborderw=5: x=10: y=10" -codec:a copy IndVsNZ.asf
```

for avoiding video quality lose i had use this parameter "-c:v libx264 -crf 20".

what is am trying to achieve is that i can drawtext on my video file without losing quality,same output file size as input file and low cpu(because it hangs my system).

I have tried various solutions on internet but cant found problem to this. If any link related to this please share. i am new to ffmpeg.

Thankyou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing different formats, different encoder implementations, and dealing with generation loss.

> The output video file size is larger then input file size.
>   The output video file loses quality of video than input video file.

Your input video stream may be a modern, efficient format such as H.264. However, the default encoder for .asf output using `ffmpeg` is msmpeg4v3 which outputs the video format MPEG-4 part 2 Microsoft variant version 3. This is an old, relatively inefficient encoder with crappy default settings. Since it is less efficient it takes more bits for the same quality. That is why adding `-c:v libx264 -crf 20` improves quality per bit because this enables a better encoder and a more modern format (H.264).

You're also re-encoding compression artifacts present in the lossy input that can further damage compressibility. This is called [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss).

If you want H.264 video then what you can do is adjust the CRF value. Give it the highest value that provides an acceptable quality. Try a range from 18-26 or so. Use the slowest `-preset` you have patience for. See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for more info.

> The cpu is going very high.

This is to be expected. Video encoding is computationally expensive. You can reduce the number of encoding threads with the `-threads` option and/or use a separate tool to throttle CPU usage, such as `nice` on Linux. But this will make encoding take longer.